# Iterate over ndarray of dtype: float?

Tags: python, numpy

How iterate over a select row for an array that is dtype="float"?

Parameters x and why to pass into the function:

```
In [8]: x = np.array([[2000,2000,2000,0,2000,2000,2000,2000,0,2000],[1400,200,1200,1000,600,1600,800,800,1200,600],[1000,780,960,940,860,980,960,860,880,1120],[1016,982,1030,992,978,958,932,980,1040,966]])
In [9]: print x
[[2000 2000 2000    0 2000 2000 2000 2000    0 2000]
 [1400  200 1200 1000  600 1600  800  800 1200  600]
 [1000  780  960  940  860  980  960  860  880 1120]
 [1016  982 1030  992  978  958  932  980 1040  966]]

In [10]: y = 4
In [11]: print y
4
```

My function: I've tried versions of this, but the real target what to iterate over in the for loop.  I tried, range(row), nditer(), etc., and I want to understand what is the best practice for iterating row by row over an ndarray? And, one step further, how to do it selectively, i.e., only row 0 and 3 when the array is dtype="float"? Currently, I get the below error.

```
def func(x,y):
    rows, columns = len(x), y
    daily_ret = np.zeros((rows,columns),dtype=float)
    for i in daily_ret:
        daily_ret[i] = (x[i]/1000) - 1
    print daily_ret
```

My error:

```
In [23]: func(x,y)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-2d375b80632e> in <module>()
----> 1 func(x,y)

<ipython-input-22-e1b1d4ace166> in func(x, y)
      3     daily_ret = np.zeros((rows,columns),dtype=float)
      4     for i in daily_ret:
----> 5         daily_ret[i] = (x[i]/1000) - 1
      6     print daily_ret

IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

In [24]: k = x/1000
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, can't you just do ``for row in daily_ret: ...``?

Comment: @jakevdp I tried this and I get the same error. 
`for row in daily_ret: daily_ret[row] = ((cumu_ret[row]/1000) - 1)`

Comment: You would get this error if ``daily_ret`` is a list rather than a numpy array. Try adding ``daily_ret = np.array(daily_ret)`` Edit: strike that. The problem is probably that ``daily_ret`` is floating point type. Try ``daily_ret = daily_ret.astype(int)`` before running the code.

Comment: Also, if you could turn this into an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it would be much easier for folks to answer your question. As it stands, I'm not even sure what function you're calling or what the arguments would be.

Comment: What line does the error happen on? Give a backtrace, it is the single most useful bit of information you could give. Why did you create a class which contains nothing and has no instance methods. What could `self = self` even hope to mean?

Comment: @jakevdp, thank you for the guidance on MCVE. I had no idea. For this problem, I've posted a solution that handles the situation when the entire array should have an operation performed, but I still don't think there is a clear answer for doing it row by row, selectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an expression like:

```
for row in daily_ret: 
    daily_ret[row] = ((cumu_ret[row]/1000) - 1)
```

`row` is an element of `daily_ret`.  If `daily_ret` is a 2d array, then `row` is a 1d array, a row of the 2d.   It is **not** an index, and can't be used as such.   `daily_ret[row]` is wrong, as is `cumu_ret[row]`.

A possible iteration is:

```
for i in range(daily_ret.shape[0]):
    daily_ret[i] = ((cumu_ret[i]/1000.) -1)
```

where `i` steps through 0,1,..., and `daily_ret[i]`, short for `daily_ret[i,:]` is a row of the array.

Or

```
for i, row in enumerate(daily_ret):
      row = ((cumu_ret[i]/1000.) - 1)
```

`enumerate` is a common Python means of getting both an element and its index.

The use of `nditer` is overkill in this context.  It's useful when experimenting on the way to writing `cython` or `c` versions, but generally not needed for Python level iteration.  It isn't faster.

```
    for i in np.nditer(daily_ret, flags=['buffered'], 
        op_dtypes=['float'], casting='same_kind'):
        i[...] = ((cumu_ret[i]/1000) - 1)
```

And it has the same issues as `for row in daily_ret`. Here `i` is an element of the array, not an index.  So it can't be used in `cumu_ret[i]`.  There is a way of making `nditer` return an index.  Or `nditer` can be setup to iterate over both `daily_ret` and `cumu_ret`.

Also it is tricky to make `nditer` iterate over just one dimension of an array.  By default it iterates element by element.

Which raises the question - why are you iterating in the first place.  Why not just:

```
 daily_ret = cumu_ret/1000. - 1
```

I haven't studied your code in detail, so can't be sure this what you want.

Comment: thank you very much for your response to my poorly written question. I appreciate it and your solution is perfect.